# object content different from within method

Tags: swift, xcode

I am encountering a strange behavior with an App I am building.

I have a struct `Record` and I create an instance of it from a NavigationViewController's child ViewController.

We can see it like this:

NavigationController (called TaskTabsController)
|
ViewController (called TaskFromController)

If I put a breakpoint, I can inspect and check the content of the object is what it should (conform to interface input data).

But when I call a method on that instance (the very next line), the different members have different or missing values.

The object instance is created from within TaskTabsController with something like so:

```
if let formVC = (viewControllers?[1] as? TaskFormViewController) {
  let rec: TaskRecord? = formVC.makeTaskRecord()
  // here the rec data are correct when I inspect the instance

  rec?.prepareData()
  // from the prepareData function, the properties are different of can't be accessed...
}
```

Ex: From controller, I can see my instance `rec` having a member `task` instance (of `Task` type) with a `name` property.
But from within the `prepareData` method, that `task` member can't display the name attached to it. (debugger says value unreadable or something like that)
Also, I can see a list of other objects, but in the method, their count is different...

Here is how makeTaskRecord method works: (from my TaskFormViewController)

In TaskFormFiewController I have a private property like so:

```
private var stepsSelected: [StepRecord] = []
```

That property is updated whit user actions.
The StepRecord is a struct. (so should be passed by value I think)

Next is the `makeTaskRecord` method in the same controller (gathering details from form elements)

```
func makeTaskRecord() -> TaskRecord? {

    guard let current_task = task
        else {
            print("TaskForm.makeTaskRecord(): Can't create a record without a Task")
            return nil
    }

    // check data validity
    var errors:[String] = []

    // generate StepRecords >>>
    if stepsSelected.count == 0 {
        errors.append("Error, no step selected")
    }
    // <<<

    // DATA OK
    if errors.isEmpty {
        let taskrecord = TaskRecord(
            id: record?.id,
            taskId: task!.id,
            userCode: Config.getUser()!.code, // global object containing login state
            pictures: [],
            memo: memo.text,
            task: current_task,
            stepRecords: stepsSelected // data here is correctly set
        )

        return taskrecord // but here, I can't retreive the stepRecords! (1)
    }
    else {
        // display errors in an alert box
        let errorVC = MyHelpers.makeAlert("Error with data", errors.joined(separator: "\n"))
        self.present(errorVC, animated: true)
        return nil
    }
}
```

Here is how the prepareData() method looks like: (method of Record class)

```
func prepareData() -> [String: Any]? {
    // no steps in record, data is invalid
    guard
        let stepRecordsJson = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self.stepRecords)
        // This is where I constated that stepRecords is different (set but empty)
    else {
        return nil
    }

    // other data
    var params = [
        "task_id": taskId,
        "user_code": userCode,
        "step_records": stepRecordsJson,  // this is what doesn't work well, but it's certainly related to (1) above
        "memo": memo ?? ""
    ] as [String : Any]

    // when editing, we set again the record ID
    if let edit_id = self.id {
        params["id"] = edit_id
    }

    return params
}
```

Note: All the data structures and `Codable` struct

In the sample above, at the (1), I put a breakpoint on the return line.
When checking data, I see that the "sub-struct" do not have good values:

```
(lldb) print current_task.name
(String) $R0 = "屋根工事"
(lldb) print taskrecord.task.name
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x6f).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

The `task` is a struct so there should not be problems about it, but the debugger can't read the task I assigned to my taskrecord.

Is there something I am missing? Like a pointer reference of some sort?

Comment: Could you perhaps show the code for prepareData()?

Comment: Is the address of the struct the same (in the debugguer)? I'm wondering Also what's the code of `makeTaskRecord()`?

Comment: @Lame the structs do not have addresses in the debugger. I suppose it is because those are values.